# Visual studio 2015. c++ compiler error C2280 attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, eigen, slam

What i am trying to do is to compile project which was built by CMake. In my code i have next method:

```
/** "in-place" version of TriangularView::solve() where the result is written in \a other
  *
  * \warning The parameter is only marked 'const' to make the C++ compiler accept a temporary expression here.
  * This function will const_cast it, so constness isn't honored here.
  *
  * See TriangularView:solve() for the details.
  */
template<typename MatrixType, unsigned int Mode>
template<int Side, typename OtherDerived>
void TriangularView<MatrixType,Mode>::solveInPlace(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& _other) const
{
    OtherDerived& other = _other.const_cast_derived();
    eigen_assert( cols() == rows() && ((Side==OnTheLeft && cols() == other.rows()) || (Side==OnTheRight && cols() == other.cols())) );
    eigen_assert((!(Mode & ZeroDiag)) && bool(Mode & (Upper|Lower)));

    enum { copy = internal::traits<OtherDerived>::Flags & RowMajorBit  && OtherDerived::IsVectorAtCompileTime };
    typedef typename internal::conditional<copy,
      typename internal::plain_matrix_type_column_major<OtherDerived>::type, OtherDerived&>::type OtherCopy;
    OtherCopy otherCopy(other);

    internal::triangular_solver_selector<MatrixType, typename internal::remove_reference<OtherCopy>::type,
      Side, Mode>::run(nestedExpression(), otherCopy);

    if (copy)
      other = otherCopy;
}
```

When i try to compile i get next error:

```
error C2280 "Eigen::Block<Derived,-1,-1,false> &Eigen::Block<Derived,-1,-1,false>::operator =(const Eigen::Block<Derived,-1,-1,false> &)": attempting to reference a deleted function
```

at line

```
other = otherCopy;
```

How can i get rid of it?

**UPD**

When i hit F12 ("Go to definition") on OtherDerived, cursor jumps to the line #332 in the following file: http://codepad.org/9zN8inib

```
template<int Side, typename OtherDerived>
void solveInPlace(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other) const;
```

(top one)

Comment: Are you sure that OtherDerived have a Copy constructer? Rule of 5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11

Comment: Does `OtherDerived` type have copy constructor?
Also, from my experience, VS can generate this type of error if compiler failed to generate default ctor or default copy ctor for any reason (e.g. one of the members does not have default ctor)

Comment: I've updated post, please check it out.

Comment: @Sleepwalker Make sure you're not stumbling upon [this bug](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=920)

Comment: @MarcoA. could you please have a look at code i've posted (updated my question one more time)?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this myself, turned out to be a [bug](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=920) in Eigen. In my case, just replacing the following line in src/Eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (!defined(__INTEL_COMPILER))
```

with

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER < 1900) && (!defined(__INTEL_COMPILER))
```

solved this issue. The assignment operators are then generated.

Comment: @tomdertech Good to hear! please accept my post as an answer if you have time.

Comment: I wasn't the OP

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to reinitialize the reference by doing

```
OtherDerived& other = _other.const_cast_derived();
```

and then

```
other = otherCopy;
```

Comment: It compiles with no changes, i still get same error. I don't understand why can't you view my code, probably you could advice me better service to share code with? It would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Your code should all be at StackOverflow for it to be a good question. I mean how would future readers benefit when the remote site removes your code? Please reduce your code to make a minimal example.