# Compiler error with eigen in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, eigen

I'm trying to run a sample code of research article. When I compile the given code, it stuck with this following error:

```
Error   C2280   'Eigen::Block<Derived,3,1,true> &Eigen::Block<Derived,3,1,true>::operator =(const Eigen::Block<Derived,3,1,true> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function    sparseicp}
```

I get this error at the following snippet in a funtion:

```
 Eigen::Matrix3Xd Qp = Eigen::Matrix3Xd::Zero(3, X.cols());
    Eigen::Matrix3Xd Qn = Eigen::Matrix3Xd::Zero(3, X.cols());

for(int i=0; i<X.cols(); ++i) {
            int id = kdtree.closest(X.col(i).data());
            Qp.col(i) = Y.col(id); // getting error at this line
            Qn.col(i) = N.col(id);
        }
```

where X, Y, and N are passing parameters to the function

```
Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived1>& X,
Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived2>& Y,
Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived3>& N,
```

I tried with the following solution, but no luck.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=920

[https://stackoverflow.com/q/43472463/4951777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472463/visual-studio-2015-c-compiler-error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-f)

[C++ Compiler Error C2280 "attempting to reference a deleted function" in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31264984/4951777)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Assignment operator with specific parameters is a deleted function which means it doesn't exist for that specific class

Comment: Which version of Eigen are you using? Make sure to use a recent one, like 3.3.4.